# In Qt, cannot generate table with setFilter / OnManualSubmit returning blank box

Tags: sql, qt

I have a relational table accessing two tables in my database, which I have attached: Items (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuN5K.png) and ItemsToStudent (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj30Y.png). My first problem is when I try to filter by rubricID and studentID, it returns an empty list. It works when I use courseID and studentID. Here is my code:

```
QSqlRelationalTableModel *model = new QSqlRelationalTableModel();
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
model->setJoinMode(QSqlRelationalTableModel::LeftJoin);
model->setTable("Items");
model->setRelation(0, QSqlRelation("ItemsToStudent", "itemID", "grade"));

qDebug() << "studentid: " << studentid;
qDebug() << "courseid: " << courseid;
model->setFilter(QString("rubricID = '"+rubricid+"' and studentID = '"+studentid+"'"));
model->select();

model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Grade"));
model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Criteria"));
model->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Max Points"));

ui->rubricTable->setModel(model);

ui->rubricTable->hideColumn(3);
```

My second problem is editing the field. When I filter by courseID and studentID I generate a table, but when I try to edit manually using QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit, it returns white (I have a save button designed for saving the values I enter). When I use OnFieldEdit, I get an error saying I can't update identity value itemID (but I'm trying to update grades).

edit: I realize now those are bad screenshots to use but I'm trying to show what columns I'm referencing. Somewhere further down the tables there are matching values.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that the filter should be like:

```
model->setFilter(QString("rubricID = %1 AND studentID = %2").arg(rubricid).arg(studentid));
```

For saving or cancelling changes you can begin a tranaction at the end if your code like:

```
model->database().transaction();
```

Code for your save button:

```
if(model->submitAll())
    model->database().commit();
else
    model->database().rollback();
```

Code for your cancel button:

```
model->revertAll();
model->database().rollback();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Out of curiosity may I ask what is the difference between your setFilter does vs what mine does?

Comment: You should make the proper condition for the filter by composing a QString. You should not append values by + argument. Also there is no need for ' character when you are using Ids which is integer.

Comment: Sorry I only just got access to the database, your answer looked right so I premature accepted your answer. I tried your setFilter method with the database connected and it is still not generating a table.